# JavaScript file to pull from JSON file no longer working

Tags: javascript, json

I had this working yesterday, but have done something to break it and can't seem to find what it is. The JavaScript is just **not creating the UL and LI elements anymore.** Sorry, but I'm still new to JavaScript (and coding in general), so debugging is still quite difficult for me, especially logic errors. I tried checking Firebug in Firefox, but I just don't see the error.

Basically the page should show a list of guitars with thumbnail pics on the left column (nav id="guitars"), then when you click one the larger column on the right populates with a larger pic and text via (the JSON file) about the guitar.

Here is my HTML source code and JavaScript:

```js
// Find links for filtering the display
var range = document.querySelectorAll('.range');

for(var link in range){
 range[link].onclick= function(){
  filter(this.dataset.low, this.dataset.high);
 }
}

var myJSON = null;
 
function filter(json,low,high){
 clear("#display");
 var display = document.querySelector("#display");
 for(var key in json){
   //UL
  var ul = document.createElement("ul");  
  var image = createImage(json[key].name, ul);  // pass the name as 'file' to our fucntion of createImage   
  for(var subkey in json[key]){
    //LI
   var li = document.createElement("li");
   var txt = document.createTextNode(subkey +" "+ json[key][subkey]);
    // key = main level of json
    // subkey = properties within each level of an object for JSON
    li.appendChild(txt);
    ul.appendChild(li);
   } // end for subkey
   display.appendChild(ul);
   } // end for key
} // end filter function


function Guitars(json){
 clear("#guitars");
 var display = document.querySelector("#guitars");
 for(var key in json){
  var ul = document.createElement("ul");  
    var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.dataset.key = key; // <li data-key="0" Yoda>
  li.onclick = viewGuitars;
  var image = createImage(json[key].name, li); // pass the name as 'file' to our fucntion of createImage  
  var txt = document.createTextNode(json[key].name);
  li.appendChild(txt);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  display.appendChild(ul);
 } // end for key
} // end filter function

function viewGuitars(){
 var single = myJSON[this.dataset.key]; /* get the single info for a JSON element, this === clicked li element in HTML */
 clear("#display");
 var display = document.querySelector("#display");
  //UL
  //if(low < json[key].cost && json[key].cost <= high){
 var ul = document.createElement("ul");  
 var image = createImage(single.name, ul);  // pass the name as 'file' to our fucntion of createImage
 for(var subkey in single){
    //LI
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var txt = document.createTextNode(subkey +" "+ single[subkey]);
    // key = main level of json
    // subkey = properties within each level of an object for JSON
   li.appendChild(txt);
   ul.appendChild(li);
  } // end for subkey 
 display.appendChild(ul);
} // end for function


function log(msg){
    console.log(msg);
}

function clear(target){
 var t = document.querySelector(target);
 
 while(t.hasChildNodes()){
  t.removeChild(t.firstChild); 
 }
}

function loadJSON(callback) {   
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'guitars.json', true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
          }
    };
    xobj.send(null);  
 }
 
 loadJSON(function(response){
 myJSON = JSON.parse(response); 
 filter(myJSON);
 // Build the character list
  character(myJSON);
 });
 
 
 function createImage(file, parent, w=50){
   //set a var to the replaced text
  //log the repalced text var
  var str = file.toLowerCase();  //Look for guitars name in JSON file and make them LowerCase, ex. return back "gibson sg"
  var filename = str.replace(/\s/g, ""); //find blank space (/\s/g | s = space, g = global) and remove it
  
  filename = ("photos/"+filename+".jpg");
  var image = new Image(); // Make a new IMG object
  image.src = filename;
  image.style.width = w+"%";
  image.style.height = "auto";
  
  image.onload = function(){
   log('good ' + file ); 
   parent.appendChild(image); //adds the image to the page!
  }
  
  image.onerror = function(){
   log('not able to load ' + filename ); 
   //parent.appendChild(image);
  }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>JSON</title>
      <style>
  #guitars {
   width:200px;
   float:left;
  }
  #guitars img {display:block}
  
  #guitars li {
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  #guitars li:hover {
   background-color: #000;
   color: #FFF;
  }
  
  #display {
   width:800px;
   float:left;
  }
  </style>
        
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav id="guitars">
            Guitar names to appear here
        </nav>

        <section id="display">
            
        </section>
        
        <script src="script.js"></script>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

...and here is my JSON file:

```html
[
  {
    "MAKE":"Gibson",
    "MODEL":"SG",
    "COLOR":"Black",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Solid, 2x pointed horns",
    "WOOD":"Mahogany",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Gibson",
    "MODEL":"Les Paul",
    "COLOR":"Gold",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Solid, 1 pointed horn, 1 rounded",
    "WOOD":"Mahogany",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Gibson",
    "MODEL":"Firebird",
    "COLOR":"Red",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Solid, \"Z\" shaped w/ rounded horns",
    "WOOD":"Mahogany",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Gibson",
    "MODEL":"Explorer",
    "COLOR":"Burgandy",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Solid, \"Z\" shaped w/ pointed horns",
    "WOOD":"Mahogany",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Gibson",
    "MODEL":"Flying V",
    "COLOR":"Yellow",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Solid, \"V\" shaped w/ pointed horns",
    "WOOD":"Mahogany",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Fender ",
    "MODEL":"Stratocaster",
    "COLOR":"Aqua Blue",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Solid, w bolt-on neck",
    "WOOD":"Alder, Ash, Poplar (varies)",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Fender ",
    "MODEL":"Telecaster",
    "COLOR":"\"Sunburst\"",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Solid, w bolt-on neck",
    "WOOD":"Alder, Ash, Poplar (varies)",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Fender ",
    "MODEL":"Jaguar",
    "COLOR":"Brown",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Solid, w bolt-on neck",
    "WOOD":"Alder, Ash, Poplar (varies)",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Fender ",
    "MODEL":"Mustang",
    "COLOR":"Bright Red",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Solid, w bolt-on neck",
    "WOOD":"Alder, Ash, Poplar (varies)",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Paul Reed Smith",
    "MODEL":"SE Standard",
    "COLOR":"Silver",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Solid, 2x pointed horns",
    "WOOD":"Maple",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Paul Reed Smith",
    "MODEL":"Dragon",
    "COLOR":"Orange",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Solid, 2x pointed horns",
    "WOOD":"Maple",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Paul Reed Smith",
    "MODEL":"McCarthy",
    "COLOR":"Dark Brown",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Solid, 2x pointed horns",
    "WOOD":"Maple",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Gretsch",
    "MODEL":"Jupiter Thunderbird",
    "COLOR":"Black",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Solid, Asymetrical shape",
    "WOOD":"Mahogany",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Gretsch",
    "MODEL":"White Falcon",
    "COLOR":"White",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Semi-hollow, 1 pointed horn, 1 rounded",
    "WOOD":"Spruce",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Gretsch",
    "MODEL":"Triple Jet",
    "COLOR":"Copper",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Semi-hollow, 1 pointed horn, 1 rounded",
    "WOOD":"Mahogany",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Electric"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Martin",
    "MODEL":"D-28",
    "COLOR":"Natural wood",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Hollow, \"dreadnought\" design",
    "WOOD":"Spruce",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Acoustic"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Martin",
    "MODEL":"D-18",
    "COLOR":"Natural wood",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Hollow, \"dreadnought\" design",
    "WOOD":"Spruce",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Acoustic"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Taylor",
    "MODEL":"310",
    "COLOR":"Natural wood",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Hollow, \"dreadnought\" design",
    "WOOD":"Rosewood",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Acoustic"
  },
  {
    "MAKE":"Taylor",
    "MODEL":"360e",
    "COLOR":"Natural wood",
    "BODY-TYPE":"Hollow, \"dreadnought\" design",
    "WOOD":"Rosewood",
    "ACOUSITC/ELECTRIC":"Acoustic"
  }
]
```

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Reduce the code to the absolute minimum to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you, Felix. I will try and do so, but am not sure what code can go and what has to stay. Will post back...

Comment: That's the process of debugging... finding out where the issue is ;)

Comment: have a look at your error console (and if you don't know where your error console is, find out). First up is this: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =` which points to this: `function createImage(file, parent, w=50){` you can't assign a value to a variable inside an argument list. Do it inside the function calling it or the function being called

Comment: Thank you, Lucas. I will look into it!

Comment: additionally, your objects have no key labeled "name", so lines like this: `var image = createImage(json[key].name, li);`  will fail. Perhaps you meant `var image = createImage(json[key].MAKE, li);`? or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

- line 8, col 1, Don't make functions within a loop. **this points to code that looks all sorts of wrong**
- line 7, col 6, Missing semicolon.
- line 103, col 38, 'default parameters' is only available in ES6 (use esnext option). **most likely cause**
- line 118, col 10, Missing semicolon.
- line 123, col 10, Missing semicolon.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jaromanda X! Not sure to use esnext option, but I am researching it now...

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "line 103, col 38, 'default parameters' is only available in ES6 (use esnext option). most likely cause"? I Googled "usenext option" but I can't seem to find how to fix this.

Comment: It's a jshint message. Informs you that the syntax is valid in es 2015